# Ambiguous coroutineContext while calling co-routine builders (launch, async) in a suspended function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a class `Runner` that implements the `CoroutineScope` interface as shown below. It has a suspended function called `run`. when I use the co-routine builder functions (`launch`, `async`) in this suspended `run` function I get the below warning

> Ambiguous coroutineContext due to CoroutineScope receiver of suspend
> function

The `Runner` class has a single coroutineContext property implemented. Can someone explain the logic behind the warning message?

```
class Runner: CoroutineScope {

    override private val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO

    suspend fun run()  {
           val job1 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job1") }
           val job2 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job2") }
           listOf(job1, job2).forEach { it.join() }
    }

}
```

Comment: So there are some different answers. I wonder what is best-practice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is ambiguous due to the suspend modifier. Your `run()` function will be called from another couroutineScope. So the `launch` builders inside it can start a coroutine or suspend within an existing coroutine. That is the ambiguity. You can fix it by removing the suspend modifier:

```
class Runner : CoroutineScope {

    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO

    fun run() = launch {
            val job1 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job1") }
            val job2 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job2") }
            listOf(job1, job2).forEach { it.join() }
        }

}
```

Comment: this makes sense.. so the public entry-point method of a CoroutineScope implementation class must be a non-suspending regular function? what is the convention regarding that?

Comment: I think the convention is to create scopes as properties instead of classes. Check [this post](https://proandroiddev.com/why-your-class-probably-shouldnt-implement-coroutinescope-eb34f722e510)

Comment: Generally speaking, you _shouldn't_ write classes implementing `CoroutineScope`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to explicitly state that `run()` uses coroutineContext of Runner, that will remove ambiguity

```
suspend fun run() = withContext(coroutineContext) {
    val job1 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job1") }
    val job2 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job2") }
    listOf(job1, job2).forEach { it.join() }
}
```

alternatively you could use the context in which run is called if you add an argument, e.g.

```
suspend fun run(cc:CoroutineContext = coroutineContext) = withContext(cc) {
    val job1 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job1") }
    val job2 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job2") }
    listOf(job1, job2).forEach { it.join() }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. is there a way to access the current coroutineContext of a suspended function without having to explicitly pass it as an argument?

Comment: actually, [there is](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/current-coroutine-context.html)

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid suspend function inside Coroutine Scoped class or function
unless it would threw the above warning

```
class Runner: CoroutineScope {

            override private val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO

            suspend fun run()  {
                   val job1 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job1") }
                   val job2 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job2") }
                   listOf(job1, job2).forEach { it.join() }
            }

        }
```

to

```
class Runner: CoroutineScope {
            //also remove the `private` visibility modifier
            override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO

            fun run()  {
                   val job1 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job1") }
                   val job2 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job2") }
                   this.launch{
                       listOf(job1, job2).forEach { it.join() }
                   }   
            }

        }
```

Comment: `.join()` is a suspend function

Comment: Could you please explain why you should "avoid suspend function inside Coroutine Scoped class or function".

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way to implement what you're trying to do is using the `corotineScope` function instead of implementing `CoroutineScope`:

```kotlin
class Runner {
    suspend fun run() {
        coroutineScope {
           val job1 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job1") }
           val job2 = launch { delay(2000); println("launching job2") }
           listOf(job1, job2).forEach { it.join() }
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want to use the IO dispatcher, which seems unnecessary in this particular example, you can instead use `withContext`:

```kotlin
suspend fun run() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ...
```

The original code and the code of most answers can behave in unexpected ways. Implementing a Coroutine Scope with a Context that has a dispatcher but does not have a Job will cause it to behave similarly to `GlobalScope`, which is marked as a delicate API for a reason, breaking Structured Concurrency.